# Annoying text every page in Laravel web app

Tags: laravel

This is driving me crazy, but for some reason I have the letters "vd" before all rendered content on each page of my site in my Laravel app. Basically the letters "vd" appear at the top of every page (website, not the actual code) before the navbar or any other content. They also appear when ever I run a *php artisan* command. For example

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Git\Webapp> php artisan view:clear
vdCompiled views cleared!
```

-- OR --

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Git\Webapp> php artisan serve
vdLaravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

I've checked all my views and can't find the letters "vd" anywhere, but figure it must be coming from something being processed before the view because I get it running simple "php artisan" commands.

I have also tried running the webapp from "C:\wamp\www\Webapp" using WAMP and still get the "vd" text.

Comment: Check if you have any unnecessary echos in you route file. Adding a simple `echo 'vd';` to the web.php route file can do the exact same thing. If not you might have made some changes to any of the bootstrapping code which might be displaying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have the "vd" string at the top of a bootstrap file, (config, service provider, route) before the php open tag!

Comment: Turns out it was in Bootstrap > cache > services.php right at the top of the file. Not sure how it got there (probably just me nodding off doing some late night coding) but thanks for pointing in the right direction. I would have never thought to look in the bootstrap folders/files and PHPStorm's search feature couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a global search in your project and find if you have vd anywhere in your whole project. may be somewhere it can be found. try to search in index.php and bootstrap.php, server.php